# How to use boost log severity in a shared library?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I'm using `boost::log` for my project.
I want to encapsulate them in a shared library, but I found my severity is not working in other app linked to the library,the argument `lvl` of function `operator<<` is always 0.

I tried to debug source code from boost, I found that there are different instance by below function when set level and get level.

```
BOOST_LOG_API uintmax_t& get_severity_level()
```

Below is my code.

In project `log-lib`:

logger.h

```cpp
#ifndef LOGGER_H
#define LOGGER_H

#include <unordered_map>

#include <boost/log/common.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/manipulators/add_value.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/sync_frontend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/text_file_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/text_ostream_backend.hpp>

#if defined(LOG_LIBRARY)
#define LOGGER_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define LOGGER_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

enum class LogLevel
{
    LOG_ALL = 0,
    LOG_TRACE,
    LOG_DEBUG,
    LOG_INFO,
    LOG_WARNING,
    LOG_ERROR,
    LOG_OFF
};

class LOGGER_EXPORT Logger
{
public:
    static Logger* Instance();

private:
    static std::shared_ptr<Logger> m_instance;
    explicit Logger();

public:
    boost::log::sources::severity_logger_mt<LogLevel>& GetLogger();

private:
    boost::log::sources::severity_logger_mt<LogLevel> m_logger;
};

#endif //LOGGER_H
```

logger.cpp

```cpp
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/console.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/sync_frontend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/text_file_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/support/date_time.hpp>

#include "logger.h"

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace attrs = boost::log::attributes;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;

using boost::shared_ptr;

std::shared_ptr<Logger> Logger::m_instance = {nullptr};

template <typename CharT, typename TraitsT>
inline std::basic_ostream<CharT, TraitsT>& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, TraitsT>& strm, LogLevel lvl)
{
    static const char* const str[] = {
        "ALL",
        "TRACE",
        "DEBUG",
        "INFO",
        "WARNING",
        "ERROR",
        "OFF"};
    if (static_cast<std::size_t>(lvl) < (sizeof(str) / sizeof(*str)))
    {
        strm << str[static_cast<int>(lvl)];
    }
    else
    {
        strm << static_cast<int>(lvl);
    }
    return strm;
}

Logger::Logger()
{
    logging::add_console_log(std::clog,
                             keywords::format = (expr::stream
                                                 << expr::format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
                                                 << "["
                                                 << expr::attr<attrs::current_thread_id::value_type>("ThreadID")
                                                 << "] "
                                                 << expr::attr<LogLevel>("Severity")
                                                 << " - "
                                                 << expr::smessage)
    );
    logging::add_common_attributes();
}

Logger* Logger::Instance()
{
    if (m_instance == nullptr)
    {
        m_instance.reset(new Logger);
    }
    return m_instance.get();
}

boost::log::sources::severity_logger_mt<LogLevel>& Logger::GetLogger()
{
    return m_logger;
}
```

and then in project `log-test`:

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "logger.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Logger::Instance();
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(Logger::Instance()->GetLogger(),LogLevel::LOG_INFO) << "test";
}
```

Does anyone know where is my mistake?

Comment: From this example it is not clear what is exactly 0. You never check anything for 0 anywhere.

Comment: @user7860670 When I debug my program , the argument `lvl` of function `operator<<` is always 0. I tried to debug source code from boost, I found that set level and get level from different instance.

Comment: ¿Are you linking boost.log as shared library?

Comment: of cause,compile and run is all ok

Comment: My point was whether you link boost.log *as shared* library. I suspect that you went with default setup which links boost.log as *static* library and end up with two instances of boost.log global state - one in exe and another in dll. So you should try to link it as shared library by defining `BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK=1` or manually. Both exe and dll should have boost dlls listed in the import section.

Comment: I got it. It must be the problem. Thank you very much!